# ASP.NET Ajax feature in existing ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a ASP.NET Website which was developed in ASP.NET 2.0.

Now I want to add a new page to the project which will make use of the ASP.NET AJAX features like Partial page updating.

Is there any options to do this ? Do i need to change any settings for this in my already existing project `/Solution` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problems you may run across is inside you web.config file if you don't go in and register the asp.net ajax assemblies.

Other than that you should be able to add a scriptmanager control and work with the page like any other asp.net ajax page.

Edit: Here is some documentation that should help you configure ASP.NET AJAX to an existing website.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx

Comment: CAn u tell me How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial about how to implement AJAX on a regular ASP.NET web site.

http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-81.aspx

Hth...